# Python Merging Excel to CSV Unicode issue

Tags: python, unicode, openpyxl

I have some sample code here in which I'm using the openpyxl library to convert all the .xlsx files in a directory to a .csv file...however I am getting a 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'' - how can I adjust the code below so the cell.value is not getting encoded if it is NoneType?  Thanks.

```
import openpyxl
import csv
from glob import glob

with open('All.csv', 'ab') as f:
    for filename in sorted(glob("*.xlsx")):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        sh = wb.get_active_sheet()
        with open('All.csv', 'ab') as f:
            c = csv.writer(f)
            for r in sh.rows:
                c.writerow([cell.value.encode("utf-8") for cell in r])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for `None` explicitly and use a substitute, probably an empty string.

```
c.writerow([b'' if cell is None else cell.value.encode("utf-8") for cell in r])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're calling `encode()` on an empty cell. You might need to add something to check if cell you're trying to add is none value and offer an alternative value you want it to include to represent nonexistence/emptiness/noneness of a cell:

```
for r in sh.rows:
    newrow = []
    for cell in r:
        if cell.value:
            newrow += cell.value.encode("utf-8")
        elif cell.value == None:
            newrow += ''
    c.writerow(newrow)
```

but to keep the niceness of your list comprehension in place we could instead you the following:

```
for r in sh.rows:
    c.writerow([cell.value.encode("utf-8") if cell.value is not None else '' for cell in r])
```